# Do I have to use an email address for Firefox extension IDs

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, gecko

I'm creating a Firefox extension that requires that I specify the `gecko.id` property in the `manifest.json` file. Everything I have found online shows an email address used as the ID. I would like to know if I have to use an email address for the ID, and, if I do, does it have to be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/applications), it looks like `gecko.id` is optional for versions of Firefox >= 48 (the addons site will generate one for the latest versions if the id is not there).

However, if you want/need to specify an id, the same documentation points you to the expected [id format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#id) page. The `id` field must be in one of the following formats:

- a [GUID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Generating_GUIDs), e.g. `{daf44bf7-a45e-4450-979c-91cf07434c3d}`;
- a string formatted like `extensionname@example.org`.

In the latter, the documentation states:

> You should not use a real email address for your `id`, however, as it
>   might attract spam.

So no, **it doesn't have to be a valid email address**, but it *can be one*.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it does not **have** to be in an email format. I do know for certain it does **not** have to be a valid email address.